# Javascript object property not accessible in callback function

Tags: javascript

I have a html page with this javascript in the body section of the page

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bhytbodL/4/) (I'm new to jsfiddle, couldn't get it to work, any help on this is appreciated to...)

The Firebug console shows me `0` in `request`, `undefined` in `onError` and `0` in `callback`. I have two questions, why can't i access `this.loadErrors` in `onError`, and how would I implement this error counter?

EDIT: the source code

```
var loader = new Loader();
loader.request(callback);

function callback(){
    console.log("loader.loadErrors in callback: " + loader.loadErrors);
}

function Loader(){
    this.loadErrors = 0;

    this.request=function(callback){
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            console.log("this.loadErrors in request: " + this.loadErrors);
            $.ajax("example", {error: onError}).done(callback);
        }
    }

    function onError(){
        console.log("this.loadErrors in onError: " + this.loadErrors);
        // this.loadErrors++;
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code messed up [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.

`onError` is called from outside of your code and it's `this` points to an unknown object (probably null).

To prevent this from happening, you have one of the two options:

1. `bind()` the `onError()` function to your `Loader` before calling it:

   ```
   this.request=function(callback){
       for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           console.log("this.loadErrors in request: " + this.loadErrors);
           $.ajax("example", {error: onError.bind(this)}).done(callback);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Bind it to the `Loader` during creation:

   ```
   var _this = this;
   function onError(){
       console.log("this.loadErrors in onError: " + _this.loadErrors);
       // _this.loadErrors++;
       callback();
   }
   ```